# ffmpeg how to control fps tbr tbn tbc parameters

Tags: ffmpeg

RT, i have two avi file,

```
A.avi: fps 30 tbr 30 tbn 30 tbc 30.
B.avi: fps 2 tbr 2 tbn 2 tbc 2.
```

the problem is how to set the same value 30 on B.avi?

Comment: thx very much, i'm using the cmd-tools :)

Comment: Such questions belong to http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg

Comment: use `-r` to set `fps`, `-video_track_timescale` to set `tbn`, refer to [ffmpeg concat compressed video result in wrong time span](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019132/6521116)

Answer (score 11):

You can change timebase or `tbn` `tbc` by `-video_track_timescale`, e. g. to change the `tbn` and `tbc` to 30:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -c:v copy -video_track_timescale 30 1.avi
```

Comment: This was helpful for me. I have a video I want to prepend with some seconds of black. The concatenated video was played much slower, the effective frame-rate only a quarter of the desired frame-rate. I was able to use `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1920x1080:rate=60:color=black -t 10 -video_track_timescale 60k black.mp4` to generate a video with a tbn matching the actual video. The tbc does not seem to be important in this context.

Answer (score 7):

You can re-encode with a specified frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -i B.avi -codec:v mpeg4 -r 30 -qscale:v 2 -codec:a copy C.avi
```

What these options mean:

- `-codec:v mpeg4` - Use the encoder called `mpeg4` for MPEG-4 Part 2
  video.
- `-r 30` - Set output frame rate as 30.
- `-qscale:v 2` - Set video output quality using a constant quantization parameter. Recommended range is 2-5 for `mpeg4`.
- `-codec:a copy` - Copy the audio from input to output to avoid re-encoding.

Note that `ffmpeg` will simply duplicate frames to achieve your desired output frame rate. If instead you were reducing your frame rate `ffmpeg` would drop frames.

Answer (score 3):

if you want more presice control, not only control fps. but also tbr, tbn, tbc.
assume you understand what mean of it.
[tbc,tbn,tbr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489/meaning-of-ffmpeg-output-tbc-tbn-tbr)

check

```
ffmpeg -x264opts timebase=???
```

or

```
ffmpeg -time_base
```

or use format factory, default it give you same tbr, tbn, tbc.

Comment: *ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -time_base 1/30 -c:a copy -c:v copy output.mp4* Is what I used. The time_base parameter successfully changed the 'tbn' to match on both videos without re-encoding. You may need to apply additional parameters if other settings need to be uniform before joining the videos.