# FFMPEG is decreasing frame rate after concat, and increasing video duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some videos and trying to `concat` them using below command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i videos_list.txt -c copy -y result.mp4
```

command is working, but the result video framerate is 11 which is less than input videos' fps (15), So the result video is becoming longer!

I tried to pass `-framerate 15` or `-fps 15` or `-r 15` but none of them worked.

Note: input videos codec are `H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)`

How can i make the result video's fps just like input videos? thanks for your helps.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57018278

Comment: @Gyan Thanks, but didn't helped

Comment: Need to see details on each input listed in `videos_list.txt`, as in something like `ffmpeg -n -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4`. Show the complete output from such command.