# FFMPEG stretches the video in second file when concatenating two mp4s

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

I'm trying to concatenate two mp4 files, which I've done successfully in other circumstances, but this time it is not working well. The two files (which are 21 minutes and 5 minutes  long respectively), when concatenated using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

result in an output file which is 52 minutes long. The first video is reproduced perfectly, but at the join the video on the second file is crawling very slowly while the audio seems to be working perfectly well. The output is reproduced below. I have noted that the video on the second file seems to have an extra option, 'q=2-31', which is very befuddling.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i Inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version n5.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ae95f466c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'Inputs.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 614 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 518 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/19/2019.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/19/2019.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 518 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/19/2019.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/19/2019.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55ae95fdfd00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter389x
frame=47386 fps=11354 q=-1.0 Lsize=  121157kB time=00:52:42.32 bitrate= 313.9kbits/s speed= 758x
video:101315kB audio:18531kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.092896%
```

What should I do to fix the issue?

Oliver B.

EDITS: FFProbe outputs

```
ffprobe -hide_banner SH433a.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SH433a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
  Duration: 00:21:19.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 616 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 518 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/19/2019.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-20T07:35:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/19/2019.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]


ffprobe -hide_banner SH433b.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SH433b.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-05-13T00:37:11.000000Z
  Duration: 00:05:01.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 649 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 480x360, 551 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 60k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-05-13T00:37:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: We can't see from your post the characteristics of the second concatenated input. Assuming you are concatenating in1.mp4 and in2.mp4, use `ffprobe -hide_banner in1.mp4` and `ffprobe -hide_banner in2.mp4`, and add the two outputs to your post.

Comment: Rotem, I have done as you asked. Thank you.

Comment: The main difference between the video streams is `30k tbn` versus `60k tbn`. Just for testing, try re-muxing the files to MKV, and concatenate the 2 MKV files. `ffmpeg -i SH433a.mp4 -c copy in1.mkv` and `ffmpeg -i SH433b.mp4 -c copy in2.mkv` and modify `inputs.txt` to concatenate in1.mkv and in2.mkv. In case it's not working, use FFprobe on  the MKV files.

Comment: That worked! Should I just leave it as a solved problem or is there a deeper thing here? Presumably I didn't lose anything by changing to mkv and then back again?

Comment: There may be better solution. What you are looking for is concatenating two videos with different timebase, without re-encoding. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57018278/ffmpeg-concat-videos-with-different-timebase) could be relevant. I don't know if `-video_track_timescale 600` is going to work.

Comment: Adding that didn't help, no.