# webm to mp4 conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, libx264, vp8

When I try to convert a webm file to mp4 the output is very very choppy and it appears as if many frames have been dropped by ffmpeg

I used the following commands to convert

```
ffmpeg -i movie.webm movie.mp4
ffmpeg -i movie.webm -vcodec libx264 movie.mp4
ffmpeg -i movie.webm -vcodec libx264 -qscale 0 movie.mp4
```

All of them have the same problem. When I use ffprobe it seems to show the frames more or less properly.

**UPDATE:**

```
 built on Jun 14 2013 14:31:50 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/user2/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/user2/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/pavan4/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/pavan4/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 35.101 / 52. 35.101
  libavcodec     55. 16.100 / 55. 16.100
  libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

Input #0, matroska,webm, from '1.webm':
  Duration: 00:00:10.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5024 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] MB rate (3600000) > level limit (2073600)
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] profile High, level 5.2
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] 264 - core 133 r2 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '1_conv4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.8.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  168 fps=0.0 q=33.0 size=      62kB time=00:00:00.11 bitrate=4606.0kbits/frame=  293 fps=230 q=33.0 size=     138kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate=4809.7kbits/

video:5620kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.212461%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] frame I:46    Avg QP:18.50  size: 39849
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] frame P:2940  Avg QP:18.27  size:  1222
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] frame B:7651  Avg QP:17.68  size:    43
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] consecutive B-frames:  4.0%  0.2%  0.3% 95.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] mb I  I16..4: 19.9% 63.2% 16.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.5%  0.1%  P16..4:  3.9%  1.1%  0.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:93.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.8%  L0:25.1% L1:74.9% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] 8x8 transform intra:63.6% inter:75.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 61.5% 53.4% 24.4% inter: 0.5% 0.5% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 52% 19% 19% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 17% 13%  4%  6%  9%  5%  8%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 18% 14%  5%  8% 10%  6%  6%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 17% 24%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] ref P L0: 82.5% 13.2%  4.0%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] ref B L0: 60.2% 39.2%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] ref B L1: 98.5%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1d966a0] kb/s:4327.77
```

Comment: A general comment about "how to ask", please add at least one of your ffmpeg command line output to see ffmpeg version and all remaining information about your input file stream to your output file stream mapping.

Comment: @alexbuisson I updated the post :) I thought I was doing something trivial so didnt add the output.

Comment: it shouldn't be so trivial, I just ran the same kind of conversion with ffmpeg ` built on Jun  4 2013 01:41:53 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)` without issue, mp4 on the output have a correct quality. Don't know how to help :(

Comment: @alexbuisson can you maybe try it on the file I have and let me know if it converts alright! link is here https://filetea.me/t1sAnxNr3xNQl22bPYc7nB59Q

Comment: sorry but that link doesn't work! Just got an empty web page.

Comment: @alexbuisson sorry I had to restart and i thought the link is persistent.. here you go again http://www.filedropper.com/1_25

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35140/discussion-between-alexbuisson-and-pavan-k)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

As your input file report a strange frame rate value `1k fps` coming from the tbs and tbr value (look [here for their definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489/meaning-of-ffmpeg-output-tbc-tbn-tbr))

the encoder generate a different result, `16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)`

So by calling :

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i 1.webm -r 24 1.mp4
```

You configure ffmpeg to generate new pts (a.k.a Presentation TimeStamp) for each frame and you set the target frame-rate to 24.

So your output mp4 file info (`ffmpeg -i ....`) change from

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4327 kb/s, 1000.09 fps, 1k tbr, 16k tbn, 2k tbc
```

to

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1670 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc
```

Comment: I just noticed this that for the mp4 ffmpeg automatically changes the bitrate to 2M while the source is at 5M. Can I set automatically the bitrate to be chosen from the source?

Comment: no idea, it's a recurrent question on SOF and SuperUser, but ask again someone may have a solution, on my side i would put every line in a script, to first run a ffmpeg -i on the input, catching&parsing the command line output to find the bitrate, and after reuse that value the set the `-b:v ` value to transcode...

Comment: this mp4 file is not playable on browser, why?

Comment: Something isnt right with this file and can't be played even with Quicktime. I wish it did work.

Answer (score 71):

## Re-mux WebM to MP4

If you want to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) and avoid re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy output.mp4
```

This will copy the VP9/VP8 video and Opus/Vorbis audio from WebM to MP4. This is like a "copy and paste". No re-encoding occurs, so no quality is lost and the process is very fast.

(Note that if you were copying only the video and not the audio, you would use `-c:v copy` instead of `-c copy`. Point being, the `-c` part is the same meaning in both cases.)

### If you get error: "opus in MP4 support is experimental"

If you get this error:

```
opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
```

Then either:

- Use a newer `ffmpeg` as Opus in MP4 is no longer experimental in newer `ffmpeg` versions.
- Or add `-strict experimental` (or the alias `-strict -2`) if you are stuck with outdated `ffmpeg`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO. Re-encoding must be avoided unless otherwise absolutely necessary.

Comment: Doesn't work, I keep getting this error: `[mp4 @ 0x5608e2b2ca00] Could not find tag for codec vp8 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`

Comment: The `-strict -2` is sensitive to placement within the `ffmpeg` command line. Neither leading (`ffmpeg -strict -2 ...`) nor trailing (`ffmpeg ... -strict -2`) worked. Adding it after the first argument, did: `ffmpeg -i input.webm -strict -2 -c copy output.mp4`.

Comment: Be aware that, using the "Re-Mux" method, you may end up with undesirable codecs...

Answer (score 34):

I summarize here the results of converting from webm to mp4 using the many command line options suggested.

We assume here that if you're asking this question, then you're forced to use webm because the Android device emulator within `Android Studio` generated it for you, and you're on a Mac so you'd really like to use `iMovie` to edit the video.

**1**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm vid-1.mp4`
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123376/webm-to-mp4-conversion-using-ffmpeg)
Takes 17.8 sec. Output file is   1.5 MB.

**2**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm -crf 1 -c:v libx264 vid-2.mp4`
Takes 18 sec. Output file is   7.6 MB.

**3**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm -crf 0 -c:v libx264 vid-3.mp4`
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379904/)
Takes 21 sec. Output file is  11.9 MB.

**4**
`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i vid.webm -r 24 vid-4.mp4`
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148739/)
Takes 0.16 sec. Output file is   1.5 MB.

**5**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm -c copy vid-5.mp4`
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60443156/)
Takes 2.8 sec. Output file is  64.6 MB.

**6**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm -strict experimental vid-6.mp4`
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426858/)
Takes 18 sec. Output file is   1.5 MB.

**7**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm -c copy -strict experimental vid-7.mp4`
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62659144/)
Takes 0.16 sec. Output file is  64.6 MB.

**8**
`ffmpeg -i vid.webm -c:v copy -strict experimental vid-8.mp4`
Also [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62659144/)
Takes 0.69 sec. Output file is  64.5 MB.

Only numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6 can be imported to `iMovie` (10.2).

The version of `ffmpeg` used is 4.3.

This is a first step. I am leaving out the more complicated quality comparison.

Perhaps the worst trap waiting for you is that `iMovie` really wants to produce a 1920x1080 movie, and so you may well get two large black bars on the side. If you're editing a demo of your app in portrait mode, you'll be wasting a lot of space. If you can, ideally you'll want to produce a video in that resolution.

The most immediate sequel question is: Assuming you truly have no need for the heavily pushed `Final Cut Pro` (because you're a programmer, not a video editor), will FCP allow you to set your own resolution?

Comment: I dont see how this comparison is useful without specifying what was the size of the INPUT file.

Comment: My favorite option number 4 - quick and small result:

ffmpeg -fflags +genpts  -i vid.webm -strict experimental -r 24 vid-4.mp4

Comment: what is the " -crf 1" part? I did a "man ffmpeg" and that option wasn't listed. My ffmpeg is on debian - "ffmpeg version 4.3.3-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
"

Comment: Option 4 runs slow for me. Anyone know why?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i A211.webm -vcodec libx265 -crf 30 -c:a copy -strict experimental A211.mp4;`
did it in 1.09s for me but with a black screen, also did all commands above

Answer (score 15):

I was able to convert by`ffmpeg -i video.webm -strict experimental video.mp4`.

Comment: `-strict experimental` is not needed when re-encoding to MP4 as in your example. However, it is needed if you want to re-mux VP8/VP9 into MP4 by adding `-c copy`.

Comment: @Ilogn, I tried yesterday without `strict` option, but I wasn't able to convert. Please, try the video at [Electric Car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9m9WDxmSN8)...it's a `webm` format video.

Comment: Works fine for me without `-strict`. I'm assuming you are getting the error `The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled`. This indicates that your ffmpeg is very old: recent versions do not need `-strict` to encode with the native FFmpeg AAC encoder.

Comment: @llogan I'm using the lastest version of FFmpeg(4.2) but still facing that error

Comment: @AminShojaei Because you are adding `-c copy` or `-c:a copy` or `-c:a libopus` to put Opus audio into MP4. This combination **was** consider experimental, but not anymore if you update to FFmpeg 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

After some hours of testing i was able to convert a matroska/webm (Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'testit1.webm') input to a mp4 output (Output #0, mp4, to 'testit1.mp4'). The video was recorded with the mediarecorder in chrome.

```
ffmpeg -i testit1.webm -c copy -strict experimental testit1.mp4
```

However by doing this we kept the small size of the webm video. But we did't have any audio. To get the audio working we used:

```
ffmpeg -i testit1.webm -c:v copy -strict experimental testit1.mp4
```

Hope this helps if you are in the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the file paths in a text file and then do this loop:

```
while read line; do ffmpeg -i "$line" -c:v libx264 -y "${line%.webm}.mp4" ;done < convert_us.txt
```

Note that the -c:v part is optional and ensures the video code is h.264.