# drag and drop conversion with FFMPEG in multiple formats

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, batch-processing

i'm looking for a script that can convert a video in 2 formats for my website : 
mp4 and Webm

i also want it to create a jpeg of the first frame and make all at 640*360

I'm a begginer with ffmpeg so i don't really know where to start. this is what i have for the moment, but that doesn't work

```
 ffmpeg -i /tmp/video.off /tmp/video.webm /tmp/video.mp4
```

the ideal situation is to have a drag and drop conversion tool, but a folder based can do the trick too

Thank you

Comment: Check this out for the 2nd part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123376/webm-to-mp4-conversion-using-ffmpeg?rq=1

Comment: perfect, thank you !