# webm to mp4 conversion using ffmpeg ubuntu

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video and I want to convert that to mp4
It is working fine for the .flv and other formats. But when I'm trying to convert webm to mp4 the video is not getting converted

```
ffmpeg -i /input.webm /output.mp4
```

It is only converting to a 48kb file. The actual size of video is 850mb

I am getting this

```
Output #0, mp4, to '/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Killed   21 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
```

It is working locally but on live server it's not generating the output as expected

Comment: Try to call ffmpeg with it's full path, maybe the user that runs the command is missing the FFMPEG environmental variable. It is also a good idea to redirect the console output into a file, so you can later examine it what went wrong.

`/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i <input> [encoding_params] <output> 2> ffmpeg_log.txt`

Pleasae not that ffmpeg uses the standard error outptut for it's default (hence the error pipe `"2>"` )

Comment: It is working fine if I'm encoding smaller videos(size is less).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG: webm to mp4 quality loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378977/ffmpeg-webm-to-mp4-quality-loss)